# Creating a new List at Runtime in Unity

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, dynamic, runtime

i try to create a list for each gameobject in a scene which stores positions and rotations of the object over a certain amount of time. I want this to happen during runtime. Because if i create a new object during runtime there should be a new seperate list for this object too. The goal is to use the values to reset the position and rotation over time. Like rewinding time. 
The problem is that i have no clue how to declare and initialize a list during runtime. I tried to store all values in one List, but that doesn't give the expected result.

I would appreciate any type of tipps or clues. Thank you.

Some Code to share my tries with all values in one list:

**Coroutine for Recording all positions and rotations in one list**

```
IEnumerator Record()
    {
        for (; ; )
        {
            Debug.Log("Recording");

            /*Limit the maximum of values stored; that limits the seconds we can go back in time*/
            if (pointsInTime.Count > Mathf.Round(rewindableObjects.Count*(1f/(Time.fixedDeltaTime/Time.timeScale)) * maxRewindTime))
            {

                for (int i = 1; i < rewindableObjects.Count; i++)
                {
                    pointsInTime.RemoveLast();
                }
            }

            foreach (GameObject go in rewindableObjects)
            {
                pointsInTime.AddFirst(new PointInTime(go.name, go.transform.position, go.transform.rotation, go.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity));

            }
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.02f/Time.timeScale);
        }
```

**Rewind function to reset all positions and rotations over time**

```
/*rewind*/
    void Rewind()
    {
        foreach(GameObject go in rewindableObjects)
        {
            if(pointsInTime.Count > 0)
            {
                PointInTime pointInTime = pointsInTime.First.Value;
                if (pointInTime.goName == go.name) //this is way to slow. Solves the problem with objects swapping positions, but looks like a diashow. Needed: Way to differantiate all values belonging to one object in a seperate list or sth. 
                {
                    go.transform.position = pointInTime.position;
                    go.transform.rotation = pointInTime.rotation;
                    go.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = pointInTime.velocity;   //not working because velocity is applyied, while the rigidbody is still kinematic!!!
                    pointsInTime.RemoveFirst();
                }

            }else StopRewind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `new List<YourTypeHere>()`?

Comment: Could you add more code for context .. we can't see e.g. what types all your fields have etc

Comment: What about a `Dictionary<GameObject, List<TheType>>` so you have a separate list linked to each `GameObject` ?

Comment: @Draco18s that doesn‘t work during  runtime. I can‘t add a Dynamic Name like Go.name + „PointsInTime“ for example. But thx. 


Thx vor your help guys!

Comment: @derHugo would it be enough to post the class „PointInTime“? The whole script is way too long and isn‘t needed for the question how to create a new list for each gameobject, 
I actually read about Dictionaries and didn‘t know how to approach this try but yes, that sounds like i should give it a shot. Can i create new Dictionary entrie during runtime?

Comment: @F.M. yes ofcourse: Either simply do `theDictionary[aGameObjectReference] = new List<TheType>();` or `theDictionary.Add(aGameObjectReference, new List<TheType>());` then later you can also access and add individual elements like e.g. `theDictionary[aGameObjectReference].Value.Add(new TheType());`

Comment: Lists are a Type, `go.name+"PointsInTime"` is a value. You couldn't do `List<"PointsInTime">` at *compile* time either.

Comment: @derHugo thank you so so much for the hint in the right direction. In German i would say: "Danke für den Denkanstoß." The dictionary was the perfect solution. I have a linkedlist for each gameobject now and can easily find the right list for the right Gameobject. It's perfect.

I would love to give you some kind of an upvote but it's not possible on comments. 

Greetings! And thank you again. 

P.s.: If you want i can share some code with you to see how i solved the problem.